# FFmpeg: Pure white image becomes gray after overlaying

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg to overlay a sticker image to another image. The problem is, the pure white sticker image becomes gray after overlaying. Here is my command:

```
-i, input.jpg, -i, white.png, -filter_complex, [1]scale=162:63[v1];[0][v1]overlay=125:337[v2], -map, [v2], -map, 0:a?, output.jpg
```

The `input.jpg` and the `white.png` are both pure white image. I create the pure white image by taking a screen shot of an empty website, and I confirm it's pure white by Color Meter(RGB=255,255,255). 
After running the command, the output image:

[image: ffmpeg output image]

I have searched Google and tried many ways like `-color_range 2`, `format=rgb24`, `-pix_fmt rgb24`, but none work for me. (Maybe I haven't  use it in the right way.) 
Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change overlay to `overlay=125:337:format=auto,format=yuvj420p` and check.

Comment: @Gyan Great! It works! In addition, can you explain what's the meaning of 
 `format=auto` and why `format=rgb24` not working? Thanks a lot!  :)

Comment: @hanswim rgb24 is not a valid choice for the format option in overlay. See the [overlay documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) for a list. Default option is `yuv420` (due to legacy) which is not ideal for your overlay due to color space conversion/subsampling. Using `format=auto` automatically chooses a more appropriate pixel format.